# I make an android camera app, but I want to rotate it 90 deg left and 90 deg right how can I do that?

Tags: android, android-camera

My camera app is ready.
Now what I wanted to do be set two buttons there into it so that when I click on one it rotates 90 degrees left and another 90 degrees right.

Comment: you mean put the camera in landscape?

Comment: yep change it into landscape without rotating the device.

Comment: by pressing the button available on screen. @DroiDev and thanx in advance.

Comment: have you tried to search stack overflow? look up how to rotate screen programmatically. you should find something pretty quick.

Answer (score 0):

use android.hardware.camera class using surface view holder

and there you can use 
 mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(180);  use different value such as 0 for rotating toward left and 180 for rotating toward right.

https://demonuts.com/android-custom-camera/